# Performance of tf inside jupyter notebooks vs. command line

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I am noticing quite significant performance (speed) differences when running tensorflow code from inside a jupyter notebook, versus running it as a script from the command line.

For example, below are the results of running the MNIST CNN tutorial (https://www.tensorflow.org/code/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/fully_connected_feed.py)

**Setup:**

AWS instance with 32 Xeon-CPUS, 62GB memory, 4 K520 GPUS (4GB mem)

Linux: 3.13.0-79 Ubuntu

Tensorflow: 0.10.0rc0 (built from sources with GPU support)

Python: 3.5.2 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)|

CUDA libraries : libcublas.so.7.5 , libcudnn.so.5, libcufft.so.7.5,  libcuda.so.1,  libcurand.so.7.5

Training steps: 2000

**Jupyter notebook execution time:**

This does *not* include time for imports and loading the dataset - just the training phase

`CPU times: user 8min 58s, sys: 0 ns, total: 8min 58s
Wall time: 8min 20s`

**Command line execution:**

This is the time for execution of the full script.

`real    0m18.803s
user    0m11.326s
sys     0m13.200s`

The GPU is being used in both cases, but utilization is higher (typically 35% during training phase for the command-line vs 2-3% for the notebook version). I even tried manually placing it on different GPUs but that doesn't make a big difference to the notebook execution time.

Any ideas / suggestions about why this might be ?

Comment: My guess is this is more of an issue between jupyter/notebooks and command line performance.  I did a quick google search, but didn't find too much there.  Is there a need for you to use the notebook or is it just a comfort thing?  I've found that a ssh terminal and a basic text editor with a ftp plugin (to copy docs back and forth) worked just as well as a notebook in most use cases I had.

Comment: Is tensorflow seeing your GPU from jupyter? Can you use log_device_placement when creating your session, as in sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True, log_device_placement=True))

Comment: Yes. It is seeing the gpu. I used log_device_placement and the logs are similar to those from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the reverse case. GPU utilisation in notebook is better than command line.

I have been training over pong using DQN, the frame speed using command line falls to 17fps, while using notebooks it falls to 100fps.

I saw nvidia-smi stats, which shows 294MB usage in command line method, 984MB usage in Jupiter notebook method.

Don't know the reason, but similar observation in colab also